# How do I install dependencies for DoctrTextlineDetector in Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, python-import, importerror

I'm doing a deepdoctection-related project. I'm following [this](https://deepdoctection.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/analyzer_with_table_transformer_notebook/) tutorial, and I get this error:

```html
ImportError: DoctrTextlineDetector has the following dependencies:
DocTr must be installed. Please check the required version either in the docs or in the setup file
Tensorflow Addons must be installed. Please check the required version either in the docs or in the setup file.Please note, that it has been announced, the this package will be deprecated in the near future.
```

on line:

```
analyzer =dd.get_dd_analyzer(config_overwrite=
```

I've installed both the modules, one additional one needed for docTR, and have imported them:

```html
pip install python-doctr
pip install tensorflow-addons
pip install tf2onnx
```

```html
import tensorflow_addons
import doctr
```

What am I missing?